# Java date with optional time

Tags: java

What is the best way to represent a date with optional time of day in Java? Possible options:

- LocalDateTime / ZonedDateTime + boolean: The additional boolean is used to distinguish midnight from a date without a meaningful time of day component
- LocalDate / ZonedDate + nullable LocalTime -> looks like the most natural option, but I do not like I need two fields
- String in ISO8601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Custom class

For a date-only value, use `LocalDate`. For a time-only value, use `LocalTime`. For a date with time but lacking the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone, use `LocalDateTime`. For a date with time in the context of an offset, use `OffsetDateTime`. For a date with time in the context of a time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`.

If you *really* want date with an optional time, I would define a class having those two fields, a `LocalDate` with a `LocalTime`, the second being null when omitted. If meant to be immutable, define that class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```
record DateWithOptionalTime ( LocalDate date , LocalTime time ) {}
```

Example usage:

```
DateWithOptionalTime x = new DateWithOptionalTime( LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , LocalTime.of( 12 , 30 ) ) ;
```

… and:

```
DateWithOptionalTime y = new DateWithOptionalTime( LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , null ) ;
```

We could add a constructor to verify the date is always supplied (call `Objects.requireNonNull`) while allowing a null time.

For convenience, add a second constructor taking only the date portion.

And we could add a `toLocalDateTime` method that returns an `Optional`. If the time-of-day field is null, this method returns an empty `Optional` object. Otherwise, this method instantiates and returns a `LocalDateTime` object. If this method were under extreme demand, you could optimize by caching internally the `LocalDateTime`, but generally I would not bother.

```java
package work.basil.example.datetime;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

public record DateWithOptionalTime( LocalDate date , LocalTime time )
{
    public DateWithOptionalTime ( final LocalDate date , final LocalTime time )
    {
        this.date = Objects.requireNonNull ( date );
        this.time = time;
    }

    public DateWithOptionalTime ( final LocalDate date )
    {
        this ( Objects.requireNonNull ( date ) , null );
    }

    public Optional < LocalDateTime > toLocalDateTime ( )
    {
        if ( Objects.isNull ( this.time ) ) return Optional.empty ( );
        return Optional.of ( LocalDateTime.of ( this.date , this.time ) );
    }
}
```

---

That said, I would double-check the thinking that led you to this design goal of a date with optional time.

Comment: It is for some tracking event information from an external system. Some events come with the exact time, others with just the date.

Answer (score 0):

A fast one without using a String pattern template , there are many pre-determined template pattern class fields , the following DateTimeFormatter is one that brings back HH:MM:SS and alike for the type and then it is removed quickly and easily. A litle piece string arranging for custom but principally...

```
java.time.LocalTime ltm = java.time.LocalTime.now();
String formtime = ltm.format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
int lascol = formtime.lastIndexOf(":");
String localformaHM = formtime.substring(0,lascol);




// ISO_DATE    '2011-12-03'   ( the UTC ofset zone +01:00)
// ISO_LOCAL_DATE    '2011-12-03'
java.time.LocalDate ltm = java.time.LocalDate.now();
String formdate = ltm.format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
int lascol = formdate.lastIndexOf("-");
String localformaYD = formtime.substring(0,lascol);





String[] sep2 = {"      "};   // THIS MUST BE A GLOBAL
boolean plsmns = false;  // possibly use as global   true=+ plus     false=- minus
//  ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME  '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'
// ISO_DATE_TIME  unknown whether the formatter will allow this with a ZonedDateTime although it appears compatible
// sometimes the formatter rejects templates based on the time object type input with the format template information it represents
java.time.ZonedDateTime ltm = java.time.ZonedDateTime.now();
String formtime = ltm.format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
//
String[] sep = formtime.split("T");
String[] dates = sep[0].split("-"); // {2001,12,03}
//
if(sep[1].indexOf("+")!=-1){
sep2 = sep[1].split("+");
plsmns = true;
}
if(sep[1].indexOf("-")!=-1){
sep2 = sep[1].split("-");
plsmns = false;
}
String[] time = sep2[0].split(":"); // {10,15,30}
// sep2[1] "01:00[Europe/Paris]"
// ... split("[");   ... etc until you have all thepieces broken down to needs
```